# Padding issue in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, padding

I currently have an issue where Firefox is taking away 1-2 pixels of padding around some text which is in a div. Before writing too much, I will show some pics and post the code so you know what I mean. It might just be the way Firefox renders. Anywho code and pics below:

Chrome/Safari/Ie Screen:

[image]

Firefox Screen:

[image]

And here is the code:

html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page One</title>
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="stylesheets/test.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="single_label blue_label">Test<div class="remove"></div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.single_label{ 
  float: left; 
  padding-right: 5px; 
  padding-left: 7px; 
  height: 14px; 
  color: black; 
  font-size: 10px; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
  text-align: left; 
  width: 74px; 
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.blue_label {
  background-color: #3acbff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

So can anyone tell me why Firefox is rendering like this and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add line-height to your css. I also suggest you to add shorthand properties.

Here is a working solution (with old/new comparsion): http://jsfiddle.net/dncxK/1/

[image]

```
.single_label {
    color:#000;
    float:left;
    font:10px/16px Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding:0 5px 0 7px;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:74px;
    height:14px;
}
```

Comment: Hey I would like to say this has fixed the problem but it has not. Regardless of what I have changed so far, FF insists on rendering it different. When I try your example FF renders it in the center then the other browsers render it down below a couple of pixels. Thanks though I really appreciate your help :D @gearsdigital

Comment: Your answer helped me the most so you get the tick :) @gearsdigital

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may have other CSS, but in the code as listed, you are never setting your line-height, so you are relying on browser defaults. Try setting a specific line-height.

Comment: No I have tried the line height but FF still renders with like a 1px difference, its so weird.

Comment: Setting line-height fixed it for me.

Comment: Ok something must be messed up with my browsers then because I changed the line height and you could still see a 1-2 pixel difference between browsers. . .

Comment: I know this one seems like such a dumb mistake but ive been trying to fix it for a while and nothing works. @chad